# Whether to use "it" or "they" when we talk about using X and Y?

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

> - Using X and Y is generally good practice, but there are also cases where **it** makes things worse or at least gives nothing.
> - Using X and Y is generally good practice, but there are also cases where **they** make things worse or at least give nothing.

X and Y are nouns.

Which sentence is more accurate?

---

***The real case:***

*(The real case is related to computer programming; and so it could be hard to understand by people who aren't developers)*

> #### Guard statements
>
> Using them is generally good practice, but there are also cases where it …​
>
> - makes the code less readable …​
>
>   ```
>   here goes an example
>   ```
> - or at least gives nothing.
>
>   ```
>   here goes an example
>   ```

Comment: Are you talking about the *act* of using X and Y making things worse, or using *X and Y* making things worse? The effect will probably be the same, in which case it doesn't matter whether you refer to the *act* as "it" or *X and Y* as "they". [Note that you use "Using X and Y **is**..." so there is presumably a single *act*.]

Comment: @AndrewLeach Good question, thanks. This is what confuses me; I cannot clearly distinguish these two things. It seems it is *act*, but I'm not sure. I added a real-life example just now.

Comment: Your real-world case only uses the singular forms of the verbs, that is it has the same structure as your first option. Are you asking whether the section on Guard Statements (which is presumably taken from a technical book, a magazine or a training manual) is correct in using that structure or are you asking something else?

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, "the real case" reflect the first option. To reflect the second option, it would be _"Using them is generally good practice, but there are also cases where **they** make the code less readable or or at least gives nothing."_  The word **they** stands for _guard statements_. The word **it** (when it used in place of "they") stands for the act of using. This is a technical manual I'm working on. I'm wondering which sentence to choose: the sentence with "it" or the sentence with "they".

Comment: In the second case (with *they*), it should read *or at least **give** nothing.*

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks, a typo. Too late to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either version could be right, and the two versions have slightly different meanings.  I think the singular version works better.

The subject of the sentence is "using," a singular noun, as further indicated by the fact that you say "is" (generally good practice) not "are" as you would if the subject were plural.

The pronoun (either it or they) is not defined but must refer to some antecedent specified earlier in the sentence.

In the version with "it" the pronoun refers to something singular - that would be "using X and Y", a singular noun.

In the version with "they" the pronoun must refer to something plural - that would be "X and Y".

I think the singular version is better because 1) then the pronoun refers to the subject of the first part of the sentence, which seems more natural and easy to parse, and 2) then the two linked parts of the sentence are more parallel, and both parts are talking about the same thing. So it is a more elegant and less clunky sentence that way.

But, I'd still say, the other version is not grammatically incorrect, and it has a slightly different meaning - that X and Y make things worse, as opposed to *using* X and Y makes things worse.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question, because the difference between the two grammatical structures is subtle but conveys distinctly different meaning.

I'll stick with your symbolic examples as they focus on the meaning of the grammar:

1. **Using X and Y** is generally good practice, but there are also cases where **it** makes things worse or at least gives nothing.
2. **Using X and Y** is generally good practice, but there are also cases where **they** make things worse or at least give nothing.

In 1., the singular pronoun "it" refers to the singular noun **phrase** "Using X and Y". When you say "it makes things worse" you mean the **whole process** of "using-x-and-y" makes things worse.

In 2., the plural pronoun "they" refers to the two discrete nouns within the noun phrase "Using X and Y." In other words, it isn't the whole process that makes things worse, it's using **just those specific values** for X and Y that makes things worse.

So they are both grammatically correct, but because they mean different things, the right choice is the one that says what you really mean.